# MariaDB configured with skip-networking, but port 3306 is open

Tags: mysql, networking, freebsd, mariadb

I have MariaDB set up on my FreeBSD [VPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) with `skip-networking` in the `my.cnf` file, since I'll never need to connect to it directly remotely.

Recently, though, I did a port scan against my own server to see if there were any surprises, and there was one - port 3306 was open. Fortunately, trying to connect to it just returns "Host is not allowed to connect" errors, but I'd rather the port just not be open at all…

If I run the same scan against my local machine, where I also have MariaDB set up with `skip-networking`, I don't see the port as open…

Is there something that would cause MariaDB to open up a port for itself despite being configured to `skip-networking`?

Comment: Port 3306 is also used by MySQL, could `mysqld` be running? (`ps aux | fgrep mysql`)

Comment: Inasmuch as MariaDB still presents itself as MySQL, I have a binary calling itself mysqld running, yes. I've never installed MySQL proper on this server, though; just MariaDB.

Comment: You can do: # netstat -tulpn | grep :3306 to find out which process opened port. Seems to me it isn't mariadb.

Comment: The binary for MariaDB is also named `mysqld`.

Comment: @G-Nugget, yes, that's what Garret wrote answering to me. This has advantages and disadvantages... I hope they won't keep it like that.

Comment: Eugene, I'm guessing `netstat -tulpn` is a Linux-ism since I'm being told most of those flags aren't valid. At any rate, `sockstat -l` does show a connection open on 3306 by `mysqld.` I'm starting to wonder if maybe the daemon isn't really using the my.cnf file I think it's using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I thought, it turned out the my.cnf file I was looking at (at `/opt/local/etc/my.cnf` was not actually being read by the daemon as it started… that's surprising, since it seems most other ports-installed programs can read configuration files from that directory just fine. After moving it to `/etc/my.cnf`, things now work as expected.

Comment: Well, according to [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html) your former location is not among the searched ones - I guess MariaDB uses the same chain of locations.